# how to have loading with jquery when ajax not complete

Tags: php, jquery

i post the information with jquery .ajax function to another page .in this time i want the user can not do any thing until the response back from server. for example show a loading on page in order to user can not click on form. any idea or plugin for that?

Comment: You can set [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), although this really means you're not using AJAX anymore. Otherwise, create some form of "Loading..." overlay and then remove it in your AJAX success callback.

Comment: thanks. **create some form of "Loading..." overlay and remove it in your AJAX success callback i did it but i think there is better way.**

Comment: StackOverflow isn't well-suited to help you find "a better way". We can help you fix bugs, correct errors, and solve problems with specific code issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a div on the screen that has a high z-index. Make it appear right before ajax call and `hide()` after you get the response from your ajax call.

Also you can use a partially transparent .png as the background of the div if you want them to still be able to see the page a little bit. Also maybe a animated loading gif.

If you have a completely transparent div they can't tell something is happening and they might sit there and try to click stuff and get frustrated that nothing is working.

If you use a completely solid div then they might think something is wrong or they went to another page or something didn't load correctly.